# Change Ionic2 Side menu items asynchronously

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

I am creating an Ionic 2 app in which the side menu items are to be loaded asynchronously. The items in the side menu will change on each and every page. As of now I have started a new Ionic 2 project with the side menu template.

The problem that I am facing is once the items are loaded in side menu, I am unable to change those items in another page.

My side menu design code is in `app.html` file and the list of items is in `app.component.ts` file. When the app loads, the items are listed in side menu but when I move to another page I am unable to change those same items.

**Is there any way to change it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had faced similar situation in one of my projects and used `Events` from 'ionic-angular' to implement dynamic side-menu functionality.

You can subscribe for a event, say "UPDATE_SIDE_MENU", in constructor of `app.component.ts` file using:

```
events.subscribe("UPDATE_SIDE_MENU", (eventData) => {
   //Logic to update Side-menu 
});
```

And whenever you move to another page, where you need to update the side menu, you can publish event in that page(usually in `ionViewWillEnter` function) using:

```
 events.publish("UPDATE_SIDE_MENU", "some event related data")
```

which will be received in your `app.component.ts` file and there you can implement code to update the side menu.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the idea. I have a small doubt. When my app.component.ts will receive the request to update the side menu, will app.html be rendered again? See I have an array of elements in app.component.ts and in app.html file I am using that array to display menu items. In your case suppose app.component receives an update request and I update the array list, will app.html show the new list?

Comment: you can hook into one of the life cycle events `ionViewDidLoad() { }` https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: @rohit-gupta I tried to implement your idea. It works. Thanx mate.

Comment: @replysam2009 You are most welcome. And, for your previous question, Answer is yes. The  app.html will show new list.

Comment: Ok, this solution works. but is there any solution like i can make a partial of side menu and make a function to update its content. then rendering that side menu in root component ? using this logic i can update side menu contents wherever i want. but the problem is that app.component.ts do not render my contents of side menu. it says that there is no provider for this ... any help ?

Comment: @RohitGupta can you provide plunker example for this i'm facing problem while implementing update_submenu_event.